# How can I get row of ListView with CursorAdapter highlighted when touch on it?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Normally when I create a `ListView` in simple ArrayAdapter. It got this highlight feature automatically without additional setup. However, when I create this `ListView` with my custom `CursorAdapter` this feature seem to be missing and I cannot find a way to solve it.

Here is my custom CursorAdapter
    public class RecentCallAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
    private final String tag = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public RecentCallAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView date;
        int nameCol;
        int dateCol;
        int numberCol;
        Calendar cal;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recentcall_item_name);
            holder.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.recentcall_item_date);
            holder.nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.CACHED_NAME);
            holder.dateCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE);
            holder.numberCol = cursor.getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER);
            holder.cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            v.setTag(holder);
        }

        String name = cursor.getString(holder.nameCol);
        if(name == null){
            name = cursor.getString(holder.numberCol);
        }       
        holder.name.setText(name);

        holder.cal.setTimeInMillis(Long.valueOf(cursor.getString(holder.dateCol)));
        holder.date.setText(Utility.calculateTimePass(holder.cal.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recentcall_item, parent, false);
        bindView(v, context, cursor);
        return v;
    }
```

Any way to solve this?
Thank.

Comment: use a selector for this purpose

Comment: selector will make highlight color becoming the same with all android version. Because I want that color to be version dependent.

Comment: color to be version dependent? i din't understand. can you post a snap shot?

Comment: for example highlight listview row on Android 2.3.3 will be plain dark blue but in Holo theme will be cyan (with some fade animation).

Comment: that has something to do with the theme not with the color.

Comment: that's why I stuck here because it supposes to have this feature in listview but somehow it disappears(when using CursorAdapter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use selector same following

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">

     </item>  
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"> 

     </item> 
    </selector>
```

and use this code in listview tag for set selector

```
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: if you want selector of android for your list .you can use this code in listview tag android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"

Comment: use drawSelectorOnTop all my items in the highlight row get covered with that drawable. only that drawable remains visible.

Comment: Ok I tried using only drawSelectorOnTop="true" and it is working only on Android 4.0.3. but, on 2.3.3 the highlighted background would go over every textview I have.

Comment: simulate selector for android 2.3.3 and place it in folder drawable-v10

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example which is working for me.

To hold the color of listview item when you press it, include the following line in your

listview layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

Then define bg_key.xml in drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
       android:state_selected="true"
       android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
     android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Finally, include this in your listview onClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
    view.setSelected(true);
    ...
}
}
```

This way, only one item will be color-selected at any time. You can define your color values in res/values/colors.xml with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your custom layout set the background as `android:background="@drawable/bkg"`

bkg.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
  <item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
  </selector>
```

normal.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"> 
  <solid android:color="#10EB0A"/>    
  <stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF" />  
  </shape>
```

pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#0FECFF"/>
</shape>
```